# Windows Phone Emulator is not compatible with this version of Windows

Tags: windows-phone-8, sdk

I'm using windows 8.1 in frensh,but visual studio 2012 in english and I want to install Microsoft windows phone SDK 8 , but i could't , i tried many times but i have always the same error :Windows Phone Emulator is not compatible with this version of Windows.
What i should do please ,

Comment: Are you downloading the correct 32 bits or 64 bits?Try installing using **Web Platform Installer**. Also are you using a Home version on windows, for developing is recommended a Professional version

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1 64bits and i'm downloading sdk 64bits

Comment: Do you have legal and RTM version of Windows 8.1? Is it Pro version of Windows? What about installing Visual Studio 2013, is it an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your version of Windows 8.1? You need AT LEAST Windows 8.1 Pro or better to be able to run Windows Phone Emulators. If your version is a standard one, you cannot use the Windows Phone 8 emulators, as your windows doesn't have HyperV

Comment: Hey , I have Windows 8.1 professional 64bits , and i tried a different version of windows phone sdk , and the same error , of compatibility

Comment: You can go to control panel > program and features and see if you have HyperV and HyperV manager installed, if not, install it before the SDK from this same point.

Comment: i checked the HyperV and its installed , i don't know really whats the problem

Comment: I tried an other version now and i have this error : A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the dated stamp in the signed file. ps :my clock is correct

Comment: That's a know bug in the installer. Please change your system date to August 1st and it will work, Microsoft is well aware of this issue and they are working in improving it.

Comment: THANK You josue , if i will change my system date, i will have a problem to open some web site like that : The site's security certificate is not yet valid!

Comment: You only need to change the system date during installation, when you finish installation, return your system to correct date and all works fine... :D

Comment: I changed the system date, and this error disappeared, but after installing i come back to the first error of compatibility.HyperV is ok , the virsion fo VS and my windows are 64bits. what i should do i'm stuck from 10 days back !